# Sitecore Package Renamed Item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I was installing a sitecore package and noticed one of the items that should have been renamed were not. I had chosen the Merge Merge option. I decided to futz around with the package install options and found that I want something between merge and overwrite.

Overwrite ends up renaming the item but it gets rid of any subitems (if they weren't part of the package). Merge seems to silently fail without telling me that it wasn't able to rename the item.

The goal is to update items that were changed in a subtree without:

A) including all of the items that are part of the subtree
B) rename items that have their names updated. If anyone has a workaround they use for this

Please let me know. This was done on Sitecore v6.6.

Answer (score 3):

You need to choose the `Merge - Clear` option:

> Leave the subtree and replace any matching items and versions with
>   those from the package but do not replace any subitems.

See [this blog post](http://www.partechit.nl/nl/blog/2012/11/sitecore-package-installation-options-explained) for an explanation of all installation options.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to rename the object. I tried using Merge - Clear as the option that a user must use while installing a package (instead of receiving a prompt) and doing it the way that a user would be prompted but neither seemed to work. Have you tried running this? In the article provided Merge - Overwrite seems to correspond to Merge - Merge. Do you know if this is true or is there actually a Merge - Overwrite option that I'm missing?

Comment: The Merge-Overwrite option does not exist. That is equal to the Merge-Merge option.